# Resolve из промисов в других процессах

Tags: node.js, процесс, promise

Имеется функция которая обрабатывает входные данные и создает массив промисов на выполнение через Promise.all([])

```
function makeSomething(param1) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            let promises = [];
            someList.forEach(i => {
                promises.push(procMessage({
                    method: 'makeRequest',
                    i: i,
                    req: {
                        userId: param1.id
                    }
                }))
            });
            return Promise.all(promises)
        }).then(data => {
            ...
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err)
        })
    })
}
```

Исходя из задания мне нужно выполнять запросы в другом процессе. Написал такую функцию:

```
function procMessage(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            let message = {
                topic: 'call_req',
                data: data
            };
            process.send(message);
        }).then(() => {
            process.on('message', msg => {
                if(msg.topic == 'call_res') {
                    if(!msg.data.err) {
                        resolve(msg.data)
                    } else {
                        reject(msg.data.err)
                    }
                }
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
}
```

В другом файле описал прием сообщений и выполнение.
Выглядит это так:

```
process.on('message', (msg: procMsg) => {
    if(msg.topic == 'call_req') {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            return makeSomethingElse(msg.data) // это вызов функции которая выполняет реквесты и возвращает промис
        }).then(data => {
            if(data['error']) {
                process.send({
                    topic: 'call_res',
                    data: data
                })
            } else {
                process.send({
                    topic: 'call_res',
                    data: data
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Оба процесса запускаю через pm2. Как итог процессы работают около 10 секунд нагрузив всё CPU по максимуму и крашатся не оставив после себя никаких логов. Пробовал ограничить вызовы через setTimeout но это повлияло только на скорость. Результат тот же.
До попытки перенести часть вызовов в другой процесс все циклы работали как часы. Что я делаю не так и как следовало бы реализовать подобный способ общения между процессами?

Answer (score 0):

У вас явно проблемы с кодстайлом. Попробуйте делать не более 3х - 4х уровней вложенности на функцию.

Если у вас грузит проц, значит у вас либо какие-то ресурсоёмкие операции (что сомнительно), либо в холостую работает сервер (что более вероятно). В приведённом коде вроде нет ничего такого. Мне кажется, проблема в `process.send`. Скорее всего вы данные не так / не туда отправляете.